# compare part of string from dropdown with a textbox in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have to compare a string value from a dropdown with a string entered in a text box. the first 4 numbers itself have to be compared and if matches - pass..
FYI- the text box will be having 16 numbers, but it has to compare only the first four number.

problem below is - it doesnt work when i try to enter more than four numbers

Thanks

```
<script>
        function display()
        {
            var a=document.getElementById("myList");
         var dropdownvalue = a.options [a.selectedIndex].text;
            var b=document.getElementById("myText").value;
            if(dropdownvalue == b) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Pass"; 
         }
            else {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=    "Fail";
         }

        }
   </script>
```

Comment: Add the html part also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

substring will help you here to grab the first 4 characters before condition check with drop down value. Something like,

```
if(dropdownvalue == b.substring(0, 4)) {
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Pass"; 
}
```

**See**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Answer (score 0):

Please use indexOf property, you can solve the problem:

```
if (dropdownvalue.indexOf(b) > 0) {
  // todo
}
```

Comment: `indexOf(b) > 0` will return true if the value of `b` is anywhere in `dropdownvalue`. OP says he wants to compare the **first four** characters.

Comment: That was an approach, anyways you can get first 4 number using b.substring(0,4);

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing the values of `dropdownvalue` and `b` with an equality comparison (`==`). If you want to compare only the first four characters, you'll need to retrieve only the first four and compare those. There are a couple of different options.

**Option 1: Substring**

```js
if (dropdownvalue == b.substring(0, 4)) {
    ...
}
```

**Option 2: String.prototype.startsWith**

```js
if (b.startsWith(dropdownvalue)) {
    ...
}
```

You didn't say if the `dropdownvalue` is always four characters, or if it's longer as well. If the `dropdownvalue` can also be more than four characters, you'll need to apply the `substring` to it in both options: `dropdownvalue.substring(0, 4)`.